# How to scan python scripts scan in Veracode static scan?

Tags: python, security, veracode

I have some python scripts(These scripts run on Airflow.) with requirements.txt. I want to scan these scripts with Veraode static scan. I tried to zip this and uploaded manually to scan this and result passed with no severity but I had a concern regarding requirement.txt(dependency libraries) that how  I will scan this. So I have created virtual environment and install all dependency libraries and then zipped it with my scripts and uploaded it, result passed but nothing is there in SCA. Is this correct way to upload and scan. What is the way to scan python scripts manually in Veracode. Currently we are trying to do scan manually and the will try to automate this with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation https://help.veracode.com/r/compilation_python you should be good if you have uploaded the scripts in a zip file.

Comment: Thanks , Are you saying only python scripts upload is fine or upload with virtual environment is fine, but what about dependency in that way dependencies does not scanned by Veracode. Not showing anything in Veracode SCA(Software Composition analysis).It should show open source libraries that I have added in virtual env or requiremets.txt

Comment: you can see in this link regarding how to package python applications, https://help.veracode.com/r/compilation_python, more precisely it states "Upload a compressed ZIP archive containing all Python and HTML code, maintaining the project structure, to Veracode. Do not include third-party packages. Do not upload individual Python source files. If using Veracode Integrated Software Composition Analysis, include Pipfile.lock in the root of your ZIP archive.", so you don't upload source libraries